# Existence of Certain Lie Groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Lie algebra (not necessarily finite dimensional). Does there necessarily exist a Lie group $G$ such that for the Lie algebra corresponding to $G$, denoted $\mathfrak{g}$, we have $\mathfrak{g} \cong \mathfrak{h}$?

I thought of this earlier today and I think the answer is no. This is not based in any intuition, the reason I think this is due to the following statement on Wikipedia (paraphrased): "If a Lie algebra corresponds to a Lie group $G$, it is typically denoted $\mathfrak{g}$." This seems to imply that given a Lie algebra, we don't necessarily have an associated Lie group.

Comment: This is called the fundamental theorem of Lie theory, Lie's theorem or the Lie-Cartan theorem and, in particular, is true.

Comment: I thought that only applied to finite dimensional Lie algebras though.

Comment: Oh, if your Lie algebras are infinite dimensional then the statement is not true. One has to specify exactly what is meant by an infinite dimensional Lie group, what exactly you mean by the Lie algebra of such a group, but for most sensible choices of these meanings the result is not true (for example, countable-dimensional Lie algebras cannot be Banach of Frechet spaces, and the Lie algebra of an infinite dimensional Lie group is usually one)

Comment: I should've specified that they don't need to be finite dimensional, I'll edit the post.

Comment: In most sources, including Wikipedia, "Lie group" typically refers to the finite-dimensional case. The significance of the Wikipedia comment is just that the same letter is being used to write both $G$ and $\mathfrak{g}$, to emphasize that the latter is the Lie algebra of the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the example of Van Est and Korthagen from $1964$, giving an infinite-dimensional (Banach) Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, so that there is no Banach Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Hence Lie's third theorem fails in the infinite-dimensional case, i.e., more precisely, it depends on how we define the concept of infinite-dimensional Lie groups. For a discussion on this, see the article [A remark on non-enlargable Lie algebras](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1239802077)
by H. Omari.